# how to use string in va_start?

Tags: c++

for some reason, i cant get this working:

```
    void examplefunctionname(string str, ...){
...
    va_start(ap, str.c_str());
```

nor do i get this work:

```
    void examplefunctionname(string str, ...){
...
    int len = str.length();
    char *strlol = new char[len+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        strlol[i] = str[i];
    }
    strlol[len] = 0;
    va_start(ap, strlol);
```

but this does:

```
    void examplefunctionname(const char *str, ...){
...
    va_start(ap, str);
```

could someone show me how i can use string instead of `const char *` there?

its outputting random numbers when i call `examplefunctionname("%d %d %d", 1337, 1337, 1337)`

Comment: Why aren't you using `va_start(ap, str)` in your examples where the function takes a `string`? You're supposed to use the name of the parameter in the `va_start` macro, not an arbitrary expression.

Comment: oh darn, i thought it reads a string there, so it takes an address to the variable... and uses that to know the last variable and then loop to next? ah.. i see it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `va_start(va_list ap, last)` ... The parameter `last` is the name of the last parameter before the variable argument list, i.e., the last parameter of which the calling function knows the type.

You've done this correctly in your working example: `va_start(ap, str)`, and `str` is the last known argument. But in the other two examples, you're passing odd things to `va_start`.

Answer (score 1):

va_start requires the previous parameter. That means that you have to pass in str directly, regardless of it's type. It does not take a const char* and it does not parse the string for you.

Answer (score 0):

`va_start` is a macro that uses the second argument as a location, you therefore need to use the last example you give.

Answer (score 0):

```
void examplefunctionname(string str, ...){
...
va_start(ap, str);
```